# Netlogo. Update an history list when turtles birth and

Tags: netlogo, auto-update, game-theory

I will be very grateful if someone could give me any kind of advice about a problem that I have in my code. I  am working on a model with four kind of agents.  Each type of agents uses a different strategy.  These strategies are Prisoner Dilemma variations.  Two of these strategies (tit for tat and unforgiving) need to record (in a list) who was the partner of interaction, and depending if that partner defected or not, will be the behave (cooperative or defect) of the agent in the next encounter with the same partner.  Agents move randomly through the world.  The problem come when agents die or birth according of their resources level.  At this point these strategies that require to record who was the previous partner and how was his behave (cooperative or defect) do not work.   This is the message that show up.
I am really appreciate any support!!!!.
[image] number of initial turtles is 42, but two ticks later the number is 52

Below is a code that reproduces the error.  In order to run it, it is necessary to create the sliders: n-tit-for-tat-com;  n-unforgiving-com; inc-ecological-resources; energy-consume-companies:

```
globals
 [
 ;;Number of companies with each strategy¨
  num-tit-for-tat-com
  num-unforgiving-com

  ;;number of interactions by each strategy
  num-tit-for-tat-com-games
  num-unforgiving-com-games

 ;; Total score of all companies playing each strategy
  tit-for-tat-com-score
  unforgiving-com-score
   
  ; Total companies en each ticks
  num-companies
]

breed [companies company]

;;create companies variables
companies-own [
  score-com
  score-com-round
  strategy-com
  defect-now?-com
  partner-defected?-com ;;action of the partner
  partnered?-com        ;;am I partnered?
  partner-com           ;;WHO of my partner (nobody if not partnered)
  partner-history-com   ;;a list containing information about past interactions with other turtles (indexed by WHO values)
  earnings-tit-for-tat-Com
  earnings-unforgiving-Com
  earnings-com
  tit-for-tat-com-score-round
  unforgiving-com-score-round
]

patches-own
[
  resources-amount ;; resources amount in each patches
  resources-to ;; aux variable to count resources taken
]

;;;Setup Procedures;;;

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  setup-companies ;;setup the turtles and distribute them randomly
  reset-ticks
end

; Setup patches
;===============
to setup-patches
  ask patches [set resources-amount random 4] ;; patches represent ecological system. Resources are distributed randomly. [0,1,2 or 3] 0 -> non resources; 3 -> plenty of resources
  ask patches [
  set pcolor (ifelse-value
      resources-amount = 0 [49]
      resources-amount = 1 [58]
      resources-amount = 2 [67]
      resources-amount = 3 [65]
      [63] ;; this case never happen. Because 4 means integer number in range [0 to 3]
    )]
end

to setup-companies
  make-companies ;;create the appropriate number of turtles playing each strategy
  setup-common-variables-com ;;sets the variables that all turtles share
end

;;create the appropriate number of turtles playing each strategy
to make-companies
  create-companies n-tit-for-tat-com
  [ set strategy-com "tit-for-tat-com"
    set color 135
    set earnings-tit-for-tat-Com random 4 + 1 ;;randomly initial resources in the range [ 1 - 4 ].  It is sum + 1 to enforce never inicial resource = 0
]
create-companies n-unforgiving-com
  [ set strategy-com "unforgiving-com"
    set color 4
  set earnings-unforgiving-Com random 4 + 1 ;;randomly initial resources in the range [ 1 - 4 ].  It is sum + 1 to enforce never inicial resource = 0
]
end

; Setup common variables
;¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
;;set the variables that all turtles share

to setup-common-variables-com
  ask companies [
    set shape "pentagon"
    set size 1.3
    set tit-for-tat-com-score-round 0
    set unforgiving-com-score-round 0
    set score-com 0
    set partnered?-com false
    set partner-com nobody
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end
    
;;;Runtime Procedures;;;

to go
  ask companies [birth-die-com]
  store-initial-companies-counts ;;record the number of turtles for each strategy
  setup-history-lists-com
  clear-last-round
  ask companies [ partner-up-com ]                        ;;have turtles try to find a partner
  let partnered-com companies with [ partnered?-com ]
  ask partnered-com [ select-strategy-com ]           ;;all partnered turtles select action
  ask partnered-com [ play-a-round-com ]
  adjust-patches

  tick
end

;Birth-die-com ;  According to the level of resources companies can die or birth
;======================
to birth-die-com
  (ifelse
       
strategy-com = "tit-for-tat-com"
  [
   set earnings-com earnings-tit-for-tat-com
(if earnings-com > 2 * energy-consume-companies [
   hatch 1 [set earnings-tit-for-tat-com random 2 + 1 ] ;;randomly initial resources in the range [ 1 - 2 ].  It is sum + 1 to enforce never inicial resource = 0
        set earnings-com (earnings-com - energy-consume-companies )])
   ( if earnings-com < energy-consume-companies [ die ])
]
strategy-com = "unforgiving-com"
  [
   set earnings-com earnings-unforgiving-com
(if earnings-com > 2 * energy-consume-companies [
   hatch 1 [set earnings-unforgiving-com random 2 + 1 ] ;;randomly initial resources in the range [ 1 - 2 ].  It is sum + 1 to enforce never inicial resource = 0
        set earnings-com (earnings-com - energy-consume-companies )])
   ( if earnings-com < energy-consume-companies [ die ])
]
  )
   end

;;STORE INITIAL COMPANIES¨
;===========================
;;record the number of turtles at the begining of each tick
;;The number of turtles of each strategy is used when calculating average payoffs.

to store-initial-companies-counts
  set num-tit-for-tat-com (count companies with [strategy-com = "tit-for-tat-com"])
  set num-unforgiving-com (count companies with [strategy-com = "unforgiving-com"])
end

;Setup-History-Lists-com;; initialize PARTNER-HISTORY list in all turtles
;========================
to setup-history-lists-com
set num-companies (count companies)
 let default-history-com [] ;;initialize the DEFAULT-HISTORY variable to be a list

  ;create a list with NUM-TURTLE elements for storing partner histories
  repeat (count companies) [ set default-history-com (fput false default-history-com) ]

  ;give each turtle a copy of this list for tracking partner histories
  ask companies [ set partner-history-com default-history-com ]
end

;Clear-last-round
;================
to clear-last-round
  let partnered-com companies with [ partnered?-com ]
  ask partnered-com [ release-partners-com ]
end

 ; release partner between companies and turn around
 ;¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
to release-partners-com
  set partnered?-com false
  set partner-com nobody
  rt 180
  set label ""
end

;;have turtles try to find a partner
;;Since other turtles that have already executed partner-up may have
;;caused the turtle executing partner-up to be partnered,
;;a check is needed to make sure the calling turtle isn't partnered.

;;partner-up.  Find partner
;===========================

to partner-up-com ;;turtle procedure
  if (not partnered?-com) [              ;;make sure still not partnered
    rt (random-float 90 - random-float 90) fd 1     ;;move around randomly
    set partner-com one-of other (companies in-radius 1 ) with [ not partnered?-com ]
    if partner-com != nobody [              ;;if successful grabbing a partner, partner up
      set partnered?-com true
      set heading 270                   ;;face partner
      ask partner-com [
        set partnered?-com true
        set partner-com myself
        set heading 90
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

;Select stratey company
;¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
;;choose an action based upon the strategy being played

to select-strategy-com ;;turtle procedure
  if strategy-com = "tit-for-tat-com" [ tit-for-tat-com ]
  if strategy-com = "unforgiving-com" [ unforgiving-com ]
end

;Play a round-companies
;¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
to play-a-round-com ;;turtle procedure
  get-payoff-com     ;;calculate the payoff for this round
  update-history-com ;;store the results for next time
end
; get-payoff-com
;¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
;;calculate the payoff for this round and
;;display a label with that payoff.

;; Strategy-companies

;Turtles   l         l
;Action    l    C    l      D
;__________l________ l__________
;  C       l    3    l     -3
;----------l---------l----------
;  D       l    5    l     -2

to get-payoff-com
  set partner-defected?-com [defect-now?-com] of partner-com
  ifelse partner-defected?-com [
    ifelse defect-now?-com 
     [ set score-com (score-com + 1 ) set label 1 set score-com-round 1 ]
    [set score-com (score-com + 0) set label 0 set score-com-round 0]
  ]
  [ifelse defect-now?-com 
      [set score-com (score-com + 5) set label 5 set score-com-round 5] 
      [set score-com (score-com + 3) set label 3 set score-com-round 3]
  ]
end

;Update-history
;¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
;;update PARTNER-HISTORY based upon the strategy being played
to update-history-com
  if strategy-com = "tit-for-tat-com" [ tit-for-tat-com-history-update ]
  if strategy-com = "unforgiving-com" [ unforgiving-com-history-update ]

end

;;;Strategies;;;

; Tit-for-tat-com
;¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
to tit-for-tat-com
 set num-tit-for-tat-com-games num-tit-for-tat-com-games + 1
  set partner-defected?-com item ([who] of partner-com) partner-history-com
  ifelse (partner-defected?-com)
  [set defect-now?-com true]
  [set defect-now?-com false]
  ask  companies in-radius 1 [
      ask patches in-radius 1 [set resources-to (resources-amount * 1)]
      ask patches in-radius 1 [set resources-amount (resources-amount - resources-to)]
      set tit-for-tat-com-score-round ( tit-for-tat-com-score-round + score-com-round )
      set earnings-tit-for-tat-com (earnings-tit-for-tat-Com + ((sum [ resources-to ] of patches in-radius 1)/ 2) + tit-for-tat-com-score-round - energy-consume-companies )
      ask patches in-radius 1 [set resources-to 0 ]
 set tit-for-tat-com-score-round 0
  ]
  end

;Tit-for-tat-com-history-update¨
;¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
to tit-for-tat-com-history-update
  set partner-history-com
   (replace-item ([who] of partner-com) partner-history-com partner-defected?-com)
end

;unforgiving-com ;  Works similar to tit-for-tat, but once the another defect, always defect
;¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
to unforgiving-com
  set num-unforgiving-com-games num-unforgiving-com-games + 1
  set partner-defected?-com item ([who] of partner-com) partner-history-com
  ifelse (partner-defected?-com)
    [set defect-now?-com true]
    [set defect-now?-com false]
 ask  companies in-radius 1 [
      ask patches in-radius 1 [set resources-to (resources-amount * 1)]
      ask patches in-radius 1 [set resources-amount (resources-amount - resources-to)]
      set unforgiving-com-score-round ( unforgiving-com-score-round + score-com-round )
      set earnings-unforgiving-com (earnings-unforgiving-Com + ((sum [ resources-to ] of patches in-radius 1)/ 2) + unforgiving-com-score-round - energy-consume-companies)
      ask patches in-radius 1 [set resources-to 0 ]
 set unforgiving-com-score-round 0
  ]
end

;unforgiving-com-history-update
;¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨¨
to unforgiving-com-history-update
  if partner-defected?-com [
   set partner-history-com
    (replace-item ([who] of partner-com) partner-history-com partner-defected?-com)
  ]
end


;; Adjusting Patches
;; Put limits
to  adjust-patches
  ask patches [ set resources-amount resources-amount + random-float  Inc-Ecological-resources ] ;; Resources are renewable. They grow up again between [0-3).  Use  Slider
  ask patches [                        ;; Resources range [0-3)
  set resources-amount (ifelse-value
    resources-amount < 0 [0] ;;
     resources-amount > 3 [3] ;;
      [resources-amount]
    )
 ]

;; Patches are colored according their level
  ask patches [
    set pcolor (ifelse-value
    resources-amount < 0 [ black ]
    resources-amount = 0 [ 38 ]
    resources-amount > 0 and resources-amount <= 0.5 [ 49 ]
    resources-amount > 0.5 and resources-amount <= 2 [ 67 ]
    resources-amount > 2 and resources-amount <= 3 [ 65 ]
    resources-amount > 3 and resources-amount <= 4  [ 63 ]
    [ white ])
  ]
 end
```

Comment: Hi Angela, it is very hard to read and work through this. Can you please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem? For example, the procedure generating the error in your screenshot (i.e. `to unforgiving-com`) is not present in your sample code.

Comment: Thanks Matteo for read my question.  I have already edited the ask question, where I changed the code for one that reproduce the error.   Have a good Weekend,